# How to show script file name in Mule log?

Tags: mule

Is there a way to customize the log message format in Mule?

We are using the 3.8(CE) runtime with a flow that has a Groovy script step. The script is defined as a file reference:

```
<scripting:component doc:name="My Script">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy" file="./groovy/test.groovy"/>
    </scripting:component>
```

The "test.groovy" script just logs a message:

```
log.info "My Groovy script started"
```

When we run the Mule flow, we're seeing this in the log:

```
INFO  2017-03-08 09:45:00,967 [[muletest].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.02] org.mule.module.scripting.component.Scriptable: My Groovy script started
```

Is there a way to add either the name of the script ("My Script") or the file name ("test.groovy") to the log messages?

Comment: Why don't you log the file name directly in groovy ?

Comment: We have some shared Groovy methods compiled into JAR files and called from multiple scripts...in my example above, think about putting the log message into one of these shared routines - it wouldn't know the name of the calling script or component. Perhaps you know a Mule variable or method that carries the file name of the currently running component or script, or some other way to get this data at execution?